# Iterator implementation in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, iterator

We can make a regular (POJSO) JS Object iterable, like so:

```
const tempObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

tempObj[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
  const self = this;
  const keys = Object.keys(self);
  return {
    next() {
      const k = keys.shift();
      return {
        done: !k,
        value: [k, self[k]]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

now we can use `for..of` loop:

```
for (let [k,v] of tempObj) {
  console.log(k,v);
}
```

and we get:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

my question is - is there another method we need to implement besides next()? if not, why did the iterator spec choose to return an object instead of just returning a function? why isn't the spec simply:

```
   tempObj[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
      return function next {
          return {
            done: Object.keys(this).length === 0,
            value: Object.keys(this).shift()
          }
      }
    };
```

my only guess is that by returning an object, it leaves room for updates/changes.

Comment: I recently implemented a [functional iterator](https://repl.it/repls/BestHorizontalOrders) without implicit mutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Iterator interface also supports two more optional methods: `return` and `throw`. From [the ES6 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iteration), section 25.1.1.2 (Table 54):

> **return**
>
> A function that returns an IteratorResult object. The returned
>   object must conform to the IteratorResult interface. Invoking this
>   method notifies the Iterator object that the caller does not intend to
>   make any more next method calls to the Iterator. The returned
>   IteratorResult object will typically have a done property whose value
>   is true, and a value property with the value passed as the argument of
>   the return method. However, this requirement is not enforced.
>
> **throw**
>
> A function that returns an IteratorResult object. The returned object
>   must conform to the IteratorResult interface. Invoking this method
>   notifies the Iterator object that the caller has detected an error
>   condition. The argument may be used to identify the error condition
>   and typically will be an exception object. A typical response is to
>   throw the value passed as the argument. If the method does not throw,
>   the returned IteratorResult object will typically have a done property
>   whose value is true.

The ES6 spec also says:

> Typically callers of these methods should check for their existence before invoking them.

So you're definitely not required to implement them; the burden of checking for their existence is on the caller.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another method we need to implement besides `next()`?

No, none that we *need* to implement, but we *can* implement `throw` and `return` for the **full [iterator interface](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iterator-interface)**. Generator objects do that, for example.

> Why did the iterator spec choose to return an object instead of just returning a function?

Because an iterator is (usually) stateful, and from an OOP viewpoint it should be an object with a method not a (pure) function. This also allows prototypical inheritance for iterator instances.

Answer (score 1):

You could yield a generator with `Object.entries` as value.

```js
let tempObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

tempObj[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield* Object.entries(this);
};

for (let [k, v] of tempObj) {
    console.log(k, v);
}
```